# Плитка div-ов отображает 5-й справа, а не слева

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Добрый день.

Есть плитка категорий http://rose.e-tickets.org.ua/cvety/
Однако почему-то 5-й элемент переносится вправо. А должен слева идти.
Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: У вас 4-й элемент имеет другую высоту. Поставьте всем блокам одну и ту же высоту и всё будет нормально

Comment: либо вставьте `<div style="clear:both"></div>` после 4го элемента. это пример, стиль, конечно же, нужно вынести в класс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Почему?

У вас элементы имеют чуть-чуть разную высоту.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И даже несмотря на разницу менее 1 пискела, из-за этого элемент и переносится на новую строку.

### Что делать?

Можно дать всем элементам фиксированную высоту (к примеру 198 или 199px) и это исправит ситуацию.

> Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Но проблема имхо вообще в использовании вёрстки с хаками float, clear и т.д.
Используйте flexbox. Если дадите контейнеру `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;` то ваши проблемы решатся.